# How to fix Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable while using mpld3?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

Python mpld3 '.show()' Gives me this error "Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable"

I know that there are many duplicates of this question here, however, I haven't been able to find a recent one.  This seems to be a common problem with mpld3.

Using Matplotlib version 3.1.3

Using mpld3 version 0.3

I'm also using Anaconda and did a conda upgrade --all and a conda update --all and still get this error.

Here is some code to reproduce the error. [It's really simple]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2]]

ax.scatter(x, y)

mpld3.show()
```

Any idea on a quick fix?  Or if someone more knowing than I, could post this somewhere where it can be addressed appropriately?

The code above is just a bare bones example to show that there are no numpy arrays being used in the plot creation itself.  It is no way a representation of what I'm trying to do [Show a matplotlib figure on a webpage in a simple way].  I know that matplotlib uses numpy internally, so it must be some issue with mpld3 parsing the figure properties dictionary.

Comment: Why are you not using `plt.show()`? What is the purpose of mpld3 here?

Comment: My goal is to show the plot on a webpage.  Otherwise, yeah, I would use plt.show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you and I was able to reproduce with your code.
I was just testing a fresh installed mpld3 when I encountered this error.

What I did to fix it is to uninstall mpld3 (which I had installed with pip) and re-install it with conda.
Then it worked.
Checking version with conda list gives me the same versions of both package as you have.
I remember reading that one should not play with both pip and conda for python package managing. I always forget to apply to this rule.

Hope it will fix it for you.

Comment: Hello Rcarl!  I have never really used any pip installations while using anaconda unless it was necessary, however, since you were able to get something working I will mark your answer as correct since I have given up on mpld3 and have opted for using Plotly instead.